# Link errors compiling a mixed objective-C/C++ project with C++11 support in xcode 4.5.2

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, linker, std

I am trying to compile a workspace of 3 projects with C++11 support. This set of projects has successfully compiled and linked using LLVM compiler defaults. In addition, the c++ code has previously compiled on a number of compilers including g++, llvm, msvc, sun, irix etc so it is very clean code.

Under the c++ language dialect section of the workspace build settings there are 3 line items:

c language dialect
c++ language dialect
c++ standard library

Using the settings:

c language dialect: compiler default
c++ language dialect: compiler default
c++ standard library: libc++ (LLVM c++ standard library with c++11 support)

I can successfully compile but get many link errors. Some are from our own functions and some are from standard functions. Here is a sample of link errors to standard functions:

(null): "std::string::find_last_of(char const*, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
(null): "std::string::size() const", referenced from:

It seemed clear that I was linking to the wrong standard library, so I investigated changing  various options above. Changing the dialect to -std=c++11 even broke my compilation. I could not find a combination that worked for me.

Can you suggest what might be wrong?

EDIT: my motivation for doing this is that I want to use std::thread in my c++ code that interfaces with objective-c (and have that c++ code still be portable)

Comment: I've been getting these kind of errors... [sorry i'll rephrase this as an answer..] meanwhile are you using latest Xcode and OSX?

Comment: I think this [site](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/mixing.html) explains this well. I am stuck on this recently and find it very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

XCode 4.5.2 / OSX 10.8.2

I've been getting these

```
(null): "std::string::find_last_of(char const*, unsigned long) const", 
 referenced from: (null):    "std::string::size() const", referenced from:
```

Variously with different versions of openCV libraries. It seems like the issue is access to the C++ standard library. In this case working settings were as follows:

Older library versions:

```
C Language Dialect GNU99[-std=gnu99]
C++ Language Dialect GNU++11[-std=gnu++11]
C++ Standard Library libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library)
```

recent library versions:

```
C Language Dialect GNU99[-std=gnu99]
C++ Language Dialect GNU++11[-std=gnu++11]
C++ Standard Library libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)
```

Toggling the standard library spec to either version yields those errors.

Answer (score 1):

I finally traced the problem to two things

1) Despite the fact I set the compiler options at the workspace level, these options were not being propagated to the constituent projects. *Something to be aware of!* So in effect different projects were being compiled with different sets of compiler libraries and dialects - so not surprising there were link errors. The combination of options that worked for me were:

**C Language Dialect** Compiler Default
**C++ Language Dialect**  -std=c++11
**C++ Standard Library** libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)

2) Under c++11 compilation, one of my projects would not compile. After fixing the syntax error, it compiled and linked fine with the above options

Answer (score 1):

While use Code 5 i had a similar problem

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"std::string::clear()", referenced from:
FormatLog(unsigned int, int, char const*, std::string&) in libMO.a(AppLog.o)
```

Changing "Deployment Target" from 7.0 to 6.0 helped me.

For XCode 4.5 it seems have to use `LLVM C++ with C++11 support` compiler instead `GNU C++` compiler for C++ Standard Library.