# C++11 Xcode 5 : linking error

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, cocos2d-x

Doing cocos2d-x 2.2.0 development on Xcode 5. Trying to get C++11 working, but it is getting some of linking errors. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

The project is on [github](https://github.com/docchang/cocos2dx_C--11).

Below are the C++11 configuration ([stackoverflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246622/link-errors-compiling-a-mixed-objective-c-c-project-with-c11-support-in-xcod)).
[image: C++11 Configuration]

I've linked `libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib` & `libz.dylib` libraries in addition to the default.
[image: Linked Libraries]

The error build log is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/92483404/cocos2dx_c%2B%2B11_error_build.log).
[image: error build log]

Comment: iOS deployment target is iOS 5.0 or newer? Did you check that cocos2d-x 2.x supports C++11? Last I remember is that only v3.x supports C++11 features.

Comment: I'm currently using C++11 in my Cocos2d-x 2.2.0 project and haven't had any problems.  Did you build the project yourself or with the provided scripts?  As an aside, I included a couple of the libraries you're trying and rebuilt and it worked fine.

Comment: @microslop please help me. Yes, the project was generated by the script. How did you do it? What are your C++ settings?

Comment: @docchang - As far as I can tell from the build settings you provided in the picture, they look correct.  Can you show us your Build log?

Comment: @microslop Just updated the description with a build log link.

Comment: @docchang Curious, what do you have in your Build Settings for Architectures for both the cocos2dx.xcodeproj and your application project?

Comment: @microslop The cocos2dx architecture is $(ARCHS_STANDARD). The project architecture is $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT). I've uploaded the entire project on github. See updated description.

Comment: @docchang Just downloaded your project and it built without issues on my end.  Have you tried downloading cocos2d-x again and testing from a clean build?

Comment: The linking errors got down from 58 to 11 after I included the `libstdc++.6.0.9`. I think I'm missing some more libraries, but don't know what else I should include. I've updated the description. @microslop what libraries are linked in your build phases?

Answer (score 3):

After I changed the target to my device instead of simulator. It just worked. Can anyone explain this?

==== update ==== (11-08-2013)
I also configured the cocos2dx target Language settings to c++11 like the project and did a clean build for both simulator and device for the coco2dx target ONLY. The project now builds fine. However, I wish I have an explanation for it. The latest changes have been committed it on github for future reference. Thanks for the support. Now I can move on.

In the light of cocos2dx & cross platform awesomeness, it took additional 3 lines of configuration(Application.mk) to get it work on Android. Sigh.......

[Reference](https://vilimpoc.org/blog/2013/10/05/c11-support-on-android-with-g-4-8/)

`Application.mk`

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCC_ENABLE_CHIPMUNK_INTEGRATION=1 -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1

APP_ABI    := armeabi
APP_CFLAGS := --std=c++11
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
```

Comment: Well, once you compiled for device you would have been building with the arm* architecture instead of i386.